# Horizontal alignment of nodes above edges

Tags: tikz-pgf

I used tikz to produce the following figure. It almost does what I want but I am wondering if there is a way to align the texts on the edges.
Specifically, I want to texts to be

1. above the edges
2. aligned to the center of the texts on the middle edge

[image]

The follow MWE puts the texts above the edges, but does not align the texts.

```
\documentclass[multi=tikzpicture, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x1) at (5,0) {$x_1$};

\node (y1) at (4,2.5) {$Y_1$};
\node (y2) at (5,2.5) {$    \cdots$};
\node (y3) at (6,2.5) {$Y_k$};

\node (mu1) at (5,5) {$    \mu_1$};

\draw (x1) edge  (y1);
\draw (x1) edge  (y2);
\draw (x1) edge  (y3);

\draw (y1) edge  (mu1);
\draw (y2) edge  (mu1);
\draw (y3) edge  (mu1);

\path (x1) edge node[above] (one) {this is $x$} (11,0);
\path (y3) edge node[above] (one) {this is $Y$} (11,2.5);
\path (mu1) edge node[above] (one) {this is $mu$} (11,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to add two of the nodes after drawing the lines, using e.g.

```
\node[above] at (one |- y3) {this is $Y$};
```

Here `(one |- y3)` means the point that has the x-coordinate of `one`, and the y-coordinate of `y3` (read `|-` as go vertically from first, coordinate, and horizontally from second).

```
\documentclass[multi=tikzpicture, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x1) at (5,0) {$x_1$};

\node (y1) at (4,2.5) {$Y_1$};
\node (y2) at (5,2.5) {$    \cdots$};
\node (y3) at (6,2.5) {$Y_k$};

\node (mu1) at (5,5) {$    \mu_1$};

\draw (x1) edge  (y1);
\draw (x1) edge  (y2);
\draw (x1) edge  (y3);

\draw (y1) edge  (mu1);
\draw (y2) edge  (mu1);
\draw (y3) edge  (mu1);

\path (x1) edge node[above] (one) {this is $x$} (11,0);
\path (y3) edge (11,2.5);
\path (mu1) edge (11,5);

\node[above] at (one |- y3) {this is $Y$};
\node[above] at (one |- mu1) {this is $mu$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]